# Как правильно передать нажатие ссылки?

Tags: php, html, get, href

```
echo '<td><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?action=start_IP&id=' . $item['id'] . '">Сканирование</a></td>';

if (isset($_GET['' . $item['id'] . ''])) die('Была нажата ссылка!');
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверять лучше на action, вот так:

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'start_IP') die('Была нажата ссылка c ID: '.$_GET['id'].'!');
```